# Set a Members Data Type in Constructor Depending on Parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class with an enum value as a parameter. It has a member `m_ConsistencyErrors`  which is a `std::set`. I would like to set the type of this member at construction depending on the value of the enum parameter.

> if TestType value is `MSG123_CONSISTENCY_TEST` I would like m_ConsistencyErrors to be of type `std::set<EnMsg123Param>`
>
> if TestType value is `MSG5_CONSISTENCY_TEST` I would like m_ConsistencyErrors to be of type `std::set<EnMsg5Param>`

Is there a clean way to achieve this or should i find another solution.

```
class CMsgConsistencyTest // : public CTestBase  // left out for simplicity
{
    enum EnTests
    {
        MSG123_CONSISTENCY_TEST,
        MSG5_CONSISTENCY_TEST,
    };
    enum EnMsg123Param
    {
        Msg123_1,
        Msg123_2
    };
    enum EnMsg5Param
    {
        Msg5_1,
        Msg5_2
    };

public:
    CMsgConsistencyTest(const EnTests TestType) //  : CTestBase(TestType)  // left out for simplicity
    {
        if (TestType == MSG123_CONSISTENCY_TEST)
        {
            ParameterType = EnMsg123Param;  // pseudo code
        }
        else if (TestType == MSG5_CONSISTENCY_TEST)
        {
            ParameterType = EnMsg5Param;  // pseudo code
        }
    }

private:
    template<typename ParameterType>
    std::set<ParameterType> m_ConsistencyErrors;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, *ParameterType* must be know all the time when you use *CMsgConsistencyTest* and when its members access to `m_ConsistencyErrors`

For that *CMsgConsistencyTest* can be a template class, example

```
#include <set>

enum EnMsg123Param
{
  Msg123_1,
  Msg123_2,
};

enum EnMsg5Param
{
  Msg5_1,
  Msg5_2,
  Msg5_3,
};

template<typename ParameterType>
class CMsgConsistencyTest // : public CTestBase  // left out for simplicity
{
  public:
    // ...
  private:
    std::set<ParameterType> m_ConsistencyErrors;
};

// and for instance

CMsgConsistencyTest<EnMsg123Param> A;
CMsgConsistencyTest<EnMsg5Param> B;
```

otherwise you may have to do something ugly and catastrophic and 'non C++' like that :

```
   CMsgConsistencyTest(const EnTests TestType) //  : CTestBase(TestType)  // left out for simplicity
    {
        if (TestType == MSG123_CONSISTENCY_TEST)
        {
            m_ConsistencyErrors = new set<EnMsg123Param>;
        }
        else if (TestType == MSG5_CONSISTENCY_TEST)
        {
            m_ConsistencyErrors = new set<EnMsg5Param>;
        }
        // else ?
        // probably need to save TestType etc
    }

private:
    void * m_ConsistencyErrors;
```

Comment: "Must" is a bit strong (a variant would also work, for example), but I agree that this is _probably_ the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes the word is too strong, I usually try not to be too categorical, this time it escaped me, not easy to do in the nuance with my level of English ^^ I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, i had another idea of doing it the other way around with `if (std::is_same<ParameterType, EnMsg123Param>::value) TestType = MSG123_CONSISTENCY_TEST;` What do you think about that? :)

Comment: @RickPat can you develop that idea writing an other question (may be with a link to that one if that can help) ? Or answering to yourself ?

Comment: @RickPat That's a good idea. And do you even need the enum after doing that?

Comment: @bruno I will think about it and write another question if i'm unsure and link it, thank you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the enum is passed to the base class to make it identifiable without downcasting it. I have 2 derived classes with the same code, but only these 2 enums different.

Comment: @RickPat Okay that's fine then